# Websphere 9: Jax-WS Call in Workmanager fails the second time

Tags: java, multithreading, jaxb, websphere, jax-ws

we have this really weird problem on Websphere 9 with JAX-WS Calls using the Workmanager (wmdefault). The first call after server start works, but the second call fails with the following error message:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://x.x.x/", local:"XResponse"). Expected elements are (none)]
```

We noticed that we receive the response, but it cannot be processed. It seems to us, that the JAXB-Context is lost and we don't know yet why. And the strange thing is, that it works outside of the work manager. And other clients work as expected in the multithreaded workmanager setting. We tried to instantiate the service new for each call, it does not work.

One thing we also noticed, is the following:

```
[11/29/19 11:05:38:403 CET] 000000f3 UnmarshalMess 1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.UnmarshalMessageContextListener installJAXBCustomBuilder attachEvent for sc= X.X  mc=7627ae189e45d5a4f02c2fe6a63c9b2e9ed6a770bd3c053c
[11/29/19 11:05:38:404 CET] 000000f3 UnmarshalMess 1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.UnmarshalMessageContextListener installJAXBCustomBuilder Registering JAXBCustomBuilder: org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBCustomBuilder@bdabf1ac for AxisOperation: {http://x.x.x/}x
```

Do you know that this JAXBCustomBuilder does? Do you have any Ideas what exactly causes the problem and how to fix it?

We use Websphere 9.0.5.0 and the Metro-Stack for the Webservice Client Implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762565/jaxb-in-websphere?rq=1

Comment: The optimizations kick in on the second call, so the failure on the second call strongly suggests bypassing the optimizations per above link might help.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately disabling IBM's Jaxb Implementation did not help, the problem still exists.