# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not determine the operation name from the SOAP Message context and javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, websphere, jax-ws

I have an application which works in Tomcat but does not work in Websphere. An external SOAP service call is executed which gives this error in production:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.out.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:680)
```

I tried reproducing this problem locally, but it fails with this error:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not determine the operation name from the SOAP Message context (for adding a message to the service log).
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:680)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:632)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:566)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
```

Again: it works in Tomcat 9, but it doesn't work in Wepshere 8.5.5.20.

Anyone has an idea how to fix above problems? I can not easily debug the applications because they are invoked with a proxy.

Comment: Different JVM so different JAXB implementation?

Comment: To @LMC's point you could try switching the JAXBContextFactory used by default on Websphere. There's another SO answer that describes how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762565/jaxb-in-websphere